# Set Attribute to html tag without a value

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to set an attribute without value to a custom HTML element. I do not want to achieve this dynamically using the JavaScript function `setAttribute`. I specifically want to set an attribute through a class variable "status" without any value. I currently am using an attribute with the value of "status" which I do not want to use: `<container status={this.status}></container>` -> `<container status="type1"></container>`.

I believe this may not be possible but I really want to achieve this. So I want to hear any strategy in achieving this. Thanks

`component.tsx`

```
class Comp extends React.Component<any, any> {

    status: "type1" | "type2" | "type3" = "type1";

    render() {
        return(
            <container {this.status}></container>
        );
    }
}
export default Comp;
```

`desired HTML output`

```
<container type1></container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class Comp extends React.Component<any, any> {

    status: "type1" | "type2" | "type3" = "type1";


    render() {
        return(
            <container {...{[this.status]: true}}></container>
        );
    }
}
export default Comp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an object (for dynamic attribute purposes) and pass an empty string to it. The output on the DOM will be an HTML5 attribute with no value.

```
var status = {type1: ''};

render() {
    return(
        <container {...status}></container>
    );
}
```